# Can't resolve 'fs' Angular upgrade from 5.2 to 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6, angular-cli-v7

I updated my angular CLI from 1.7 to 7~, and I am getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/edit-json-file/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Projects\Dell.Studio.UI\Dell.Studio.UI.API\node_modules\edit-json-file\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonpath/generated/parser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Projects\Dell.Studio.UI\Dell.Studio.UI.API\node_modules\jsonpath\generated'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonpath/lib/grammar.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Projects\Dell.Studio.UI\Dell.Studio.UI.API\node_modules\jsonpath\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/r-json/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Projects\Dell.Studio.UI\Dell.Studio.UI.API\node_modules\r-json\lib'
```

I don't use fs anywhere in my code, its one of the node modules which does it. I have already tried installing **advanced-json-path**, and I get the same error. I have tried installing **fs** as well, but that doesn't help either. What's wrong?

This is how my package.json looks

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.9",
    "@handsontable/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "@swimlane/dragula": "^3.7.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^14.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/dragula": "^2.1.34",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/html2canvas": "0.0.35",
    "ang-jsoneditor": "^1.7.3",
    "angular-confirmation-popover": "^4.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-split": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.2.1",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "^3.0.1",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "deep-object-diff": "^1.1.0",
    "easy-json-schema": "0.0.2-beta",
    "edit-json-file": "^1.2.1",
    "events": "^3.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "flatted": "^2.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "handsontable": "^7.0.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "json-to-json-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "jsoneditor": "^5.31.1",
    "jsonpath": "^1.0.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "nested-property": "0.0.7",
    "ng-block-ui": "^2.1.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng-sidebar": "^8.0.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "https://github.com/Sky4CE/ng2-bootstrap-modal/tarball/v.1.0.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker": "^0.1.4",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-linq": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-accordion": "0.0.17",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-datetime-picker": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^3.0.2",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-toasta": "^0.1.0",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "object-rename-keys": "^1.2.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pretty-easy-date-check": "^1.2.4",
    "replaceall": "^0.1.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "^11.11.3",
    "advanced-json-path": "^1.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.11",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.14.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Some of you dependencies are probably not compatible. From what version of Angular do you uprgrade from?

Comment: Angular 5.2.0 to 7 ish

Comment: Personally I always use : https://update.angular.io/ when I update my Angular apps. Give it a try.

Comment: @Sox- I did that. This is happening after that..